# High inode usage of nfs mount

Tags: linux, inode

The data files of my application are stored in an NFS mount of a Linux system.
The inode capacity of the NFS share is approx 300 MB. Now there are two directories where the data files are generating.

```
# df -ih /nfs
/nfs/dir/abc
/nfs/dir/abc/xyz
```

If I move all the files from `/nfs/dir/abc` to `/nfs/dir/abc/xyz,` will the inode usage reduce the /nfs filesystem?

Comment: Not exactly understanding the question. However, if worried about inodes usage, you might want to use another filesystem in the NFS server.

Comment: Sadly. Using another is not an option for me. in application, the codes write to sub-directories of /nfs.
Let me explain again.
My application is writing files in the below locations;
/nfs/dir/abc and /nfs/dir/abc/xyz. 
/nfs is a nfs filer on my system. it has a inode capacity of 350MB. Currently the inode usage is 70%, approx. 245MB of inode is used. Now if i move all the files from /nfs/dir/abc to /nfs/dir/abc/xyz, will be inode usage of /nfs reduce, ie, will it go down than the current utilisation of 245MB?